# Get wildcarnames from string template

Tags: javascript, string, templates, wildcard

Is there a quick way (a known way I mean) to get wildcard names from a string template?, something like...

```
const str = `Hello ${name}, today is ${weekday}!`;
getWildCards(str); // will return ['name', 'weekday']
```

I'm creating a translation tool and the `translation` function will not know the wildcards in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Actually, it turns out there's a native way to extract the params from a template literal using [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals), which allow you to parse template literals with a function of the form:

```
function tag(strings, param1, param2, ..., paramN) { ... }
```

So, if instead of using variables inside the expressions of your template literal (`${ foo }`) you use strings (`${ 'foo' }`), then if you do:

```
tag`${ 'a' }${ 'b' } - XXX ${ 'c' }`
```

`strings` will be `['', '', ' - XXX ', '']` and you will receive 3 params with values `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.

You can return whatever you want from a tag function, so a good solution for your use case would be to return a pair `[paramsList, closure]`, where the closure will be a function that receives an object (map) with the params being used in the original string literal and uses them to build the resulting string. Like this:

```js
function extractParams(strings, ...args) {
  return [args, dict => {   
    return strings[0] + args
      .map((arg, i) => dict[arg] + strings[i + 1]).join('');
  }];
}

const [params, translate] = extractParams`Hello ${ 'name' }, today is ${ 'weekday' }`;

console.log(params);
console.log(translate({ name: 'Foo', weekday: 'Barday' }));
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Assuming that template string is wrapped into a function so that it doesn't throw a `ReferenceError`, and that you change a bit the format of your template strings so that the arguments used are always properties from an object, you could use a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for that:

Let's say you have something like this:

```js
function getSentence(key, args = {}) {
  // Note that for the proxy solution to work well, you need to wrap each of them
  // individually. Otherwise you will get a list of all the params from all the
  // sentences.

  const sentences = {
      salutation: (args) => `Hello ${ args.name }, today is ${ args.weekday }!`,
      weather: (args) => `Today is ${ args.weather } outside.`,
  };

  return sentences[key](args) || '';
}

function extractParams(key) {
  const params = [];
  
  const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
    get: (target, name) => {
      params.push(name);
    },
  });
  
  getSentence(key, proxy);
  
  return params;
}

console.log(extractParams('salutation'));
```

Anyway, note this will only work if you just have one level depth in your args, otherwise you will need a proxy that returns another proxy that returns another proxy... and keep track of the path (`prop.subprop...`). They should also return a `function` that returns a `string` for the last property that will be interpolated in the resulting string.

```js
function getSentence(key, args = {}) {
  // Note that for the proxy solution to work well, you need to wrap each of them
  // individually. Otherwise you will get a list of all the params from all the
  // sentences.

  const sentences = {
      salutation: (args) => `Hello ${ args.name }, today is ${ args.a.b.c.d }!`,
      weather: (args) => `Today is ${ args.weather } outside.`,
  };

  return sentences[key](args) || '';
}

function getProxy(params, path = []) {
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get: (target, name) => {
      if (typeof name === 'symbol') {
        params.push(path);
        
        return () => ''; // toString();
      } else {
        return getProxy(params, path.concat(name));
      }
    },
  });
}

function extractParams(key) {
  const params = [];
  
  getSentence(key, getProxy(params));
  
  return params;
}

console.log(extractParams('salutation'));
```

Comment: @r01010010 Check my update, probably that's a better solution.